# Creating new window then closing it causes memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, new-window

I am generating new windows via the code below and displaying a webpage there and then close it. But after a while software gives out of memory exception. So there is memory leak happening. What might be the cause and how to solve it ? Thank you.

**This is how do i start new window . i am doing a loop so there are being started thousands of new windows. As you can see after 60 seconds new window get itself close.**

```
NewWindowThread<TitleWindow, string>(c => new TitleWindow(c), "the url that is going to be displayed at new window");
```

---

```
private void NewWindowThread<T, P>(Func<P, T> constructor, P param) where T : Window
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
         T w = constructor(param);
         w.Show();
         w.Closed += (sender, e) => w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}

public class TitleWindow : Window
{
    WebBrowser webnew = new WebBrowser();
    public TitleWindow(string srUrl)
    {              
         DockPanel dk = new DockPanel();
         dk.Width = 900;
         dk.Height = 600;
         this.AddChild(dk);
         webnew.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(wbMain_Navigated);

         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer3 = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
         dispatcherTimer3.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick3);
         dispatcherTimer3.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 60, 0);
         dispatcherTimer3.Start();

         webnew.Height = 600;
         webnew.Width = 900;
         dk.Children.Add(webnew);
         webnew.Navigate(srUrl);

         this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    void dispatcherTimer_Tick3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
         this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are "thousands of new windows", you're just running out of memory (and there's no memory leak).

Comment: What have you tried? Why don't you just use a memory profiler to figure this out?

Comment: What possible reason could you have to open thousands of windows?

Comment: There are not being thousands of windows at the same time :) It is like i am displaying 20000 websites. So it start from 1 open it. After 60 seconds each window getting closed down. At the same time there are being like 60 or 90 windows depending on how fast i am opening. If i give interval 1 sec there are being 60 window open at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I immediately suspect that the `WebBrowser` control is **not releasing it's resources** when the window is closed as **you are not calling** it's `Dispose()` method. The [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control is a thin wrapper around the ActiveX MSHTML control.

Add a callback on the window `Closing` or `Closed` events to do this. e.g. `webnew.Dispose()`.

Comment: Indeed, closing a window is not sufficient. It is not gone then.

Comment: Thanks a lot tried also that. But as the time passes and software runs the memory usage keep increasing :( I think it is still not sufficient enough. Still not releasing memory properly somehow. The rest of the software is very simple. Just a loop which opens new windows. So it is not the issue.

Comment: Where? In your posted sample code, I cannot see that you have tried this. You may have more than one problem. What version of Windows and Internet Explorer do you have installed?

Comment: Trying with windows 7 ultimate sp1 and internet explorer 9. Also adding dispose gives one another error after long time run. http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/3622/errorbh.png